# Finding a disabled component of a gameobject and enabling it again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a Key that disables a the MeshRenderer and the BoxCollider components of the current GameObject. After these are disabled and the user presses the same Key again, I want to enable these same components again but it does not seem to be able to find these components as they are disabled. How would I be able to find these two components and enable them again? Thanks in advance!
Here is a link to the script that I am using (I disable the components on lines 27+28 inside of a function, and I am trying to enable them again on lines 36+37 inside of a function as well): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/702cf5630bfc7236ba52f6ec8d7cd7a4

Edit: Or maybe tell me what mistake I made.

Comment: It should find the components. This case is valid for disabled gameobjects, you can not find it unless you have a reference to it. Show us the code that calls "ShowStrut" function.

Comment: It is in the code.

Comment: Ohh, i missed that.. Can you please confirm with `debug.log` that the function is being called through RPC?

Comment: Is there a reason for not just caching a reference to those components and keeping them as fields?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just iterate over all component and enable/disable it ?

```
var allComponents : Component[];
allComponents = gameObject.GetComponents (Component);
for (var component : Component in allComponents) {
    // check here if this component is of interest may be by checking
    // tag and if it is of interest do the following
    //enable disable 
    component.enabled = !component.enabled;
}
```

**[Edit]**
unity v 5.3

```
public Component[] GetComponentsInChildren(Type t, bool includeInactive = false);
```

will return you all the active and inactive game objects if includeInactive is true.
So you do the following now

```
Component [] compList = yourGameObj.GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(Component));
//or type of game object 
foreach(Component comp : compList){
  //do your magic
}
```

**[Edit]**
We are not here to babysit and I currently dont have Unity installed in the PC I am using right now, but nevertheless the code will look something like this (correct to suit your needs):

```
public class Strut : Photon.MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool DestroyByRpc;


    private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    private BoxCollider boxCollider;

    void Start(){
        Component [] compList = yourGameObj.GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(MeshRenderer), true);
        if (compList != null && compList.Length > 0)
            meshRenderer = compList[0];
        compList = yourGameObj.GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(BoxCollider), true);
        if (compList != null && compList.Length > 0)
            boxCollider = compList[0];


    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("LandingStruts")) {
            if (this.gameObject.activeSelf == true) {
                this.photonView.RPC("HideStrut", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered);
            } 
            else {
                this.photonView.RPC("ShowStrut", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered);
            }
        }


    }

    [RPC]
    public IEnumerator HideStrut()
    {
        meshRenderer.enabled = false;
        boxCollider.enabled = false;
        yield return 0;
        PhotonNetwork.UnAllocateViewID(this.photonView.viewID);
    }

    [RPC]
    public IEnumerator ShowStrut()  
    {
        meshRenderer.enabled = true;
        boxCollider.enabled = true;

        yield return 0;
        PhotonNetwork.UnAllocateViewID(this.photonView.viewID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please write this in C#.

Comment: @alexo1001  The only "major" difference is: foreach (Component comp in allComponents) { comp.enabled = !comp.enabled }, which doesn't change the concept itself...

Comment: What would I replace comp and compList with inside of my script?

Comment: It gives me an error message saying: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Component' to `UnityEngine.MeshRenderer'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: may be try meshRenderer = (MeshRenderer)compList[0];

Comment: Still doesn't work. It just doesn't enable the components again. Also doesn't show an error message.

Comment: how about SetActive() ?

Comment: if mesh renderer is not null then something else may be wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can keep references of components in your code, So you don't need to get them all the time.
Here is an example:

```
public class Strut : Photon.MonoBehaviour
{
    MeshRenderer _meshRenderer;
    BoxCollider _collider;

    void Start()
    {
        _meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ();
        _collider= GetComponent<BoxCollider> ();

    }

    [RPC]
    public IEnumerator HideStrut()
    {
        _meshRenderer.enabled = false;
        _collider.enabled = false;
        yield return 0;
        PhotonNetwork.UnAllocateViewID(this.photonView.viewID);
    }

    [RPC]
    public IEnumerator ShowStrut()  
    {
        _meshRenderer.enabled = true;
        _collider.enabled = true;
        yield return 0;
        PhotonNetwork.UnAllocateViewID(this.photonView.viewID);
    }
```